# Programmatic nested list

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, repeater

I'm trying to create a nested list in Asp.Net/C# using a ListView control. I looked at lots of examples but I can't seem to make any sense of them.

Here's the pattern:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1 - level 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 - level 1</li>
    <li>Item 3 - level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1 - level 2</li>
            <li>Item 2 - level 2</li>
            <li>Item 3 - level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've created a list, which uses a single level, so it's not properly nested with regards to html - just a flat list of `<li>` tags.

However, I'd like to make changes.

Only one level will have a sub-menu - and it's possible that some level-1 items will not have any child items - so I'm looking for a pattern that could render 0 or 1 sub-menu.

Anyone know what I need to do with the following code to achieve what I want?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="LV_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <nav>
            <ul class="content-nav">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="liMenuItem" runat="server">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkMenuItem" runat="server"
            CssClass="content-nav_link"></asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

        protected void LV_ItemDataBound(object source, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.Item;

            if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {
                var data = (ContentNavItem)item.DataItem;

                var liMenuItem = item.GetControl<HtmlGenericControl>("liMenuItem");

                // Do something with the item here
            }
        }

void Build()
{
    var currentId = MenuItems.First(x => x.Route == CurrentUrl).Id;

    var currentItems = MenuItems
        .Where(x => x.IsTopLevel || x.ParentId == currentId)
        .OrderBy(x => x.GroupId).ThenBy(x => x.Anchor);

    lv.DataSource = currentItems;
    lv.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to create the menu as a string with a `StringBuilder`. But if you really want recursive controls you can clone the control and re-use it for every menu level. I use a Repeater for this demo because it's better suited for repeating items. So first we create a class and some demo data

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> menuitems { get; set; }
}
```

Fill it with dummy data

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<MenuItem> MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { name = "Name " + i });

        if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8)
        {
            MenuItems[i].menuitems = new List<MenuItem>();
            MenuItems[i].menuitems.Add(new MenuItem() { name = "SubName 1" });
            MenuItems[i].menuitems.Add(new MenuItem() { name = "SubName 2" });
            MenuItems[i].menuitems.Add(new MenuItem() { name = "SubName 3" });

            if (i == 8)
            {
                MenuItems[i].menuitems[0].menuitems = new List<MenuItem>();
                MenuItems[i].menuitems[0].menuitems.Add(new MenuItem() { name = "SubName 1" });
                MenuItems[i].menuitems[0].menuitems.Add(new MenuItem() { name = "SubName 2" });
                MenuItems[i].menuitems[0].menuitems.Add(new MenuItem() { name = "SubName 3" });
            }
        }
    }

    Repeater1.DataSource = MenuItems;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Add the Repeater control to the page. Also with a PlaceHolder so it can hold a copy of itself.

```
<nav>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul class="content-nav">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li id="liMenuItem" runat="server">
                <%# Eval("name") %>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</nav>
```

Now in the ItemDataBound event we make a clone of `Repeater1`, fill it with the submenu, add it to the PlaceHolder of the parent Repeater and attach a ItemDataBound programaticallty so that Repeater then can generate it's own children.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = e.Item.DataItem as MenuItem;

    //check if the item exists and if it has subitems
    if (item != null && item.menuitems != null)
    {
        //determine type and get the properties
        Type type = sender.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
        Object obj = type.InvokeMember("", BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, sender, null);

        //copy the properties
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, propertyInfo.GetValue(sender, null), null);
            }
        }

        //cast the created object back to a repeater
        Repeater nestedRepeater = obj as Repeater;

        //fill the child repeater with the sub menu items
        nestedRepeater.DataSource = item.menuitems;

        //attach the itemdatabound event
        nestedRepeater.ItemDataBound += Repeater1_ItemDataBound;

        //bind the data
        nestedRepeater.DataBind();

        //find the placeholder and add the created Repeater
        PlaceHolder ph = e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
        ph.Controls.Add(nestedRepeater);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. But I would build just a string recursively. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396778/recursive-menu-builder-with-c-sharp. But I've posted an answer to show it could be done with Control elements.